# Nginx processes running, but don't remember installing or running it

Tags: nginx

I've just checked my `top` output and I have 4 instances of `nginx` running under user `nobody`.

This is a web server (Ubuntu 18.04) used for a couple of sites, but all of them should be running under `apache2` so I have absolutely no clue why nginx would be started.

I tried stopping it with `sudo service nginx stop`, but I received the error `Failed to stop nginx.service: Unit nginx.service not loaded.`.

Top output:

```
31002 nobody    20   0   49660   7288    904 S 11.8  0.4 121:50.10 nginx
31003 nobody    20   0   50360   7988    904 S 11.8  0.4 121:52.87 nginx
31004 nobody    20   0   49660   7764   1380 S 11.8  0.4 121:47.32 nginx
31005 nobody    20   0   49472   7100    904 S 11.8  0.3 121:46.10 nginx
```

It's eating almost 50% of my cpu. What is it even running? Would something break if I stopped it? How do I stop it?

EDIT:

`lsof` output

```
sudo lsof -p 31002
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
nginx   31002 nobody  cwd       DIR              252,1     4096    527275 /opt/ng99
nginx   31002 nobody  rtd       DIR              252,1     4096         2 /
nginx   31002 nobody  txt       REG              252,1   630136    527281 /opt/ng99/sbin/nginx
nginx   31002 nobody  mem       REG              252,1    31680      3544 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.27.so
nginx   31002 nobody  mem       REG              252,1   258040      2023 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_systemd.so.2
nginx   31002 nobody  DEL       REG                0,5          332894646 /dev/zero
nginx   31002 nobody  mem       REG              252,1    47568      3266 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.27.so
nginx   31002 nobody  mem       REG              252,1    97176      3256 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.27.so
nginx   31002 nobody  mem       REG              252,1    47576      3268 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.27.so
nginx   31002 nobody  mem       REG              252,1    39744      3263 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.27.so
nginx   31002 nobody  mem       REG              252,1    14560      3232 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
nginx   31002 nobody  mem       REG              252,1  2030544      3212 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
nginx   31002 nobody  mem       REG              252,1   116960      2192 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
nginx   31002 nobody  mem       REG              252,1  2361888      4958 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
nginx   31002 nobody  mem       REG              252,1   465096     13944 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.3
nginx   31002 nobody  mem       REG              252,1    39208      3218 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.27.so
nginx   31002 nobody  mem       REG              252,1   144976      3542 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so
nginx   31002 nobody  mem       REG              252,1   170960      2798 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
nginx   31002 nobody  DEL       REG               0,18          332894660 /[aio]
nginx   31002 nobody  DEL       REG                0,5          332894648 /dev/zero
nginx   31002 nobody    0u      CHR                1,3      0t0         6 /dev/null
nginx   31002 nobody    1u      CHR                1,3      0t0         6 /dev/null
nginx   31002 nobody    2w      CHR                1,3      0t0         6 /dev/null
nginx   31002 nobody    3u     unix 0xffff91167bbab000      0t0 332894651 type=STREAM
nginx   31002 nobody    4w      CHR                1,3      0t0         6 /dev/null
nginx   31002 nobody    5u     IPv4          332894647      0t0       TCP *:7080 (LISTEN)
nginx   31002 nobody    6u     unix 0xffff91167bbaa800      0t0 332894650 type=STREAM
nginx   31002 nobody    7u  a_inode               0,13        0      9574 [eventpoll]
nginx   31002 nobody    8u  a_inode               0,13        0      9574 [eventfd]
nginx   31002 nobody    9u  a_inode               0,13        0      9574 [eventfd]
nginx   31002 nobody   10u     unix 0xffff9116040f0c00      0t0 332894653 type=STREAM
nginx   31002 nobody   11u     unix 0xffff9116040f1c00      0t0 332894655 type=STREAM
nginx   31002 nobody   12u     IPv4          353160515      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->46.217.159.225:65414 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   13u     IPv4          353157436      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->mbl-82-60-103.dsl.net.pk:58900 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   14u     IPv4          353160894      0t0       TCP example.com:53940->hosted-by.leaseweb.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   15u     IPv4          353160810      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->mail2.jenty-spedition.com:63067 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   16u     IPv4          353160425      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->cust38-37-249-197.netcabo.co.mz:49548 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   17u     IPv4          353159606      0t0       TCP example.com:52448->hosted-by.leaseweb.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   18u     IPv4          353159799      0t0       TCP example.com:52676->hosted-by.leaseweb.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   19u     IPv4          353160336      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->194.red-81-43-205.staticip.rima-tde.net:64736 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   20u     IPv4          353077137      0t0       TCP example.com:39648->hosted-by.leaseweb.com:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx   31002 nobody   21u     IPv4          353159735      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->remote.ajax-mach.co.uk:15672 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   22u     IPv4          353159444      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->106.red-88-26-216.staticip.rima-tde.net:58409 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   23u     IPv4          353160361      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->234.86.232.180.dsl.static.inet.as18190:56522 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   24u     IPv4          353160107      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->195-70-120-40.stat.cablelink.at:26742 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   25u     IPv4          353160338      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->117.120.26.2:54749 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   26u     IPv4          353159878      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->mail.dzzemun.org.rs:20545 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   27u     IPv4          353160275      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->118.69.70.132:59654 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   28u     IPv4          353160819      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->host-80-17-254-205.business.telecomitalia.it:61051 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   29u     IPv4          353157413      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->202.52.248.178:52803 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   30u     IPv4          353160704      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->2e41ee77.skybroadband.com:49596 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   31u     IPv4          353160895      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->static.vnpt.vn:61600 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   32u     IPv4          353158288      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->31.223.154.37:52304 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   33u     IPv4          353161162      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->213.150.194.253:57229 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   34u     IPv4          353159044      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->14.114.175.72:9964 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   35u     IPv4          353160340      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->51-15-183-135.rev.poneytelecom.eu:58993 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   36u     IPv4          353160363      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->static.vnpt.vn:49440 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   37u     IPv4          353160665      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->140.red-2-136-150.staticip.rima-tde.net:56142 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   38u     IPv4          353124052      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->113.88.165.73:3554 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   39u     IPv4          353159348      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->41.80.67.201:55093 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   40u     sock                0,9      0t0 353161261 protocol: TCP
nginx   31002 nobody   41u     IPv4          353160799      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->host-2-116-29-249.business.telecomitalia.it:51897 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   42u     IPv4          353160426      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->www.euroconforto.com:56049 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   43u     IPv4          353159875      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->static-190-181-19-211.acelerate.net:59739 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   44u     IPv4          353156742      0t0       TCP example.com:49064->hosted-by.leaseweb.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   45u     IPv4          353160666      0t0       TCP example.com:53716->hosted-by.leaseweb.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   46u     IPv4          353156036      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->41.182.173.9:62750 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   47u     IPv4          353160113      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->117.198.240.57:51943 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   48u     IPv4          353160276      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->94.205.243.114:50083 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   49u     IPv4          353139004      0t0       TCP example.com:56416->hosted-by.leaseweb.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   50u     IPv4          353160812      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->eopy320.static.otenet.gr:52781 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   51u     IPv4          353159047      0t0       TCP example.com:51818->hosted-by.leaseweb.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   52u     sock                0,9      0t0 353161189 protocol: TCP
nginx   31002 nobody   53u     IPv4          353148651      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->183.63.101.59:52427 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   54u     IPv4          353160114      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->ppp-87-203-220-170.home.otenet.gr:52758 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   56u     sock                0,9      0t0 353161217 protocol: TCP
nginx   31002 nobody   57u     IPv4          353159483      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->27.17.52.90:57389 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   58u     IPv4          353160494      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->176.204.253.232:52539 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   31002 nobody   59u     IPv4          353160642      0t0       TCP example.com:7080->static.77.89.237.94.tmg.md:22596 (ESTABLISHED)
```

All these `example.com` are a legitimate site I am running (using [Invision power board](https://invisioncommunity.com/)), but it should be using Apache, not nginx.

`pstree` output:

```
pstree -a
systemd --system --deserialize 38
  ├─PM2 v3.5.1: God
  │   ├─node
  │   │   ├─sh -c next start -p 8080
  │   │   │   └─node /home/leonardo/wordpress-react/node_modules/.bin/next start -p 8080
  │   │   │       └─10*[{node}]
  │   │   └─10*[{node}]
  │   └─9*[{PM2 v3.5.1: God}]
  ├─accounts-daemon
  │   └─2*[{accounts-daemon}]
  ├─agetty -o -p -- \\u --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 ttyS0 vt220
  ├─apache2 -k start
  │   ├─apache2 -k start
  │   │   └─63*[{apache2}]
  │   ├─apache2 -k start
  │   │   └─63*[{apache2}]
  │   └─apache2 -k start
  │       └─63*[{apache2}]
  ├─atd -f
  ├─cron -f
  ├─dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
  ├─do-agent --syslog
  │   └─7*[{do-agent}]
  ├─login -p --
  │   └─bash
  ├─lvmetad -f
  ├─lxcfs /var/lib/lxcfs/
  │   └─10*[{lxcfs}]
  ├─master -w
  │   ├─pickup -l -t unix -u -c
  │   └─qmgr -l -t unix -u
  ├─mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
  │   └─32*[{mysqld}]
  ├─networkd-dispat /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
  │   └─{networkd-dispat}
  ├─nginx
  │   ├─nginx
  │   ├─nginx
  │   ├─nginx
  │   └─nginx
  ├─opendkim -x /etc/opendkim.conf
  │   └─opendkim -x /etc/opendkim.conf
  │       └─5*[{opendkim}]
  ├─php-fpm7.0
  │   ├─php-fpm7.0
  │   └─php-fpm7.0
  ├─php-fpm7.2
  │   ├─php-fpm7.2
  │   ├─php-fpm7.2
  │   └─php-fpm7.2
  ├─polkitd --no-debug
  │   └─2*[{polkitd}]
  ├─rsyslogd -n
  │   └─3*[{rsyslogd}]
  ├─ssh-agent -s
  ├─sshd -D
  │   └─sshd
  │       └─sshd
  │           └─bash
  │               └─pstree -a
  ├─systemd --user
  │   └─(sd-pam)
  ├─systemd --user
  │   └─(sd-pam)
  ├─systemd-journal
  ├─systemd-logind
  ├─systemd-network
  ├─systemd-resolve
  ├─systemd-timesyn
  │   └─{systemd-timesyn}
  ├─systemd-udevd
  ├─unattended-upgr /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
  │   └─{unattended-upgr}
  └─uuidd --socket-activation
```

`netstat` output:

```
sudo netstat -tlpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31001/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29988/mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:12301         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      948/opendkim
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20528/systemd-resol
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26277/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1306/master
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      22794/node
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      4144/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      26277/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1306/master
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      4144/apache2
```

Again, I recognise all of these except for the nginx one.

EDIT2:
Tried to kill the processes but new ones were started immediately.

EDIT3:
I ran ps -Al and found there was a parent process that was likely creating the processes I saw above. Once I killed that they disappeared. It's fixed for now I guess, still kind of concerning.

EDIT4:
I uploaded the /opt/ng99 folder to mega, you can find it [here](https://mega.nz/folder/JWwCyQQC#AhkXi19xH9k3Rh6gghWNTA)

Comment: Wonder if they are legitimate nginx processes or some kind of malware... you should check the full path of the executable.

Comment: @Massimo How would I do that?

Comment: `dpkg -s nginx
dpkg-query: package 'nginx' is not installed and no information is available`
That's not good is it

Comment: `lsof -p 31002` - check what files it touches. Also `pstree -a` should help you to find which process started them. `netstat -tlpn` - check on which ports it is listening. Are they blocked on the firewall? After that, you may think about the next steps. You may be using unknowingly some tool which uses nodejs as a backend, or it may be a hack, or just accidental install. Let you pust the command outputs relevant to nginx for more feedback.

Comment: I am using stuff with Node.js as a backend, is that what it is? I thought Node just started its own servers

Comment: Added outputs to the OP

Comment: I didn't see any obvious malware in the binary, and virustotal didn't either, but it is listening on port 7080, which is a port used by the well known rootkit Haxdoor. This is why so many connections are being made to it. I would delete the whole directory first, then kill the process, and see what happens. But you should be prepared to consider the system compromised and blow it away.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for updating the original description with the `pstree/lsof/netstat` outputs.

Let you check the `/opt/ng99` folder. I suggest to you to tar.gz/zip it before doing any changes. Not a standard name/location for the nginx server.

I would not be surprised if it was created under nobody user.
If so, make sure that nobody or any other regular user cannot create folders under /opt.

If you believe that not you or nobody else with the root access to that server created `/opt/ng99`, then also backup /etc and /var/logs for future investigation. Backup /root/.bash_history as well. You should not see there any commands which you did not do.

Make sure that you apache is running with the correct permissions. It happens time to time that there is a website hack which creates some process in `/tmp` or the virtualhost `upload` folder, but it should not happen in `/opt` unless you allowed some user processes to elevate its permissions (suid bit for example).
It may still happen that you wanted to test something and you installed it in `/opt/ng99` yourself. But based on what you have already said - it seems unlikely.
The key point: don't panic. Don't remove the evidence.

--edit--

I searched for the port 7080 and I found the following reference to Backdoor.Haxdoor.E [Symantec-2005-080212-3505-99] (2005.08.01)  https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=7080

You may like to read a bit more about it and how to prevent the attacks. Also consider changing passwords, just in case. If you used them elsewhere, change them too. Just in case.

Comment: Okay so, I uploaded /opt/ng99 to Mega and added a link to it in the OP. I checked all the user logs as well as command history, there are no IPs I didn't recognise or commands that could cause this. Obviously this could've happened before the login logs I can see (start of september) so I'm not entirely sure. The Nginx folder doesn't seem to have anything weird in it.

Comment: I'm not too sure how to proceed, the processes are stopped and haven't restarted on their own so it doesn't seem malicious. More than anything I'm wondering how to stop them from reappearing if I restart the server. Will deleting the `/opt/ng99` folder work? Permissions for `/opt` are `drwxr-xr-x`, which I think should be correct.

Comment: Well, IF (we don't know) it is a hack, the most common ones I have seen were script-kiddie like ones where there was some well known web exploit (e.g. Wordpress) and the script automatically installed something like a bitcoin miner. Usually you can find that in apache logs the n99 somewhere (unless it is already too old and the logs rotated). If you find it there, then you know where it came from and you may try to understand the problem (or at least update to the latest version of common cms like wordpress). If you cannot find it there it just means that you still don't know what happened.

Comment: Apache logs have most likely been rotated. I guess there's not much I can do at this point?

Comment: I think I found the culprit. I ran `chkrootkit`, it made me aware of `/tmp/.kerneltmp/nginx
/tmp/.kerneltmp/certs/server.crt
/tmp/.kerneltmp/certs/server.key` which are very obviously the cause of the problem. What should I do?

Comment: Always check the permissions and timestamps, backup and search logs for the paths. Unless you remove the original issue, you are still in trouble. Sometimes you can do some improvements with a strict firewall and and limited permissions for apache and other public facing apps. The security experts would say for sure: rebuild the system. So do not trust it until you know how they put it there.

Comment: Fair, I will move the server. Thank you for your help.